# Pasar string a DateTime y Tomar solo fecha de DateTime.Now[Actualizado]

Tags: c#, datetime

Al crear un objeto producto que tiene un campo DateTime ese campo lo lleno con un 
`DateTime.Now`
ese dato se guarda en un txt asi 03/09/2018 08:42:18 p.m y al tratar de sacar el dato de nuevo con un `DateTime.Parse(corte[2])` me sale que `no se puede reconocer la cadena como un comando date time valido`
tambien probre con

```
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
DateTime.ParseExact(corte[2], format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

gracias a un usuario me puse a buscar si `corte[2]` estaba tomando bien el valor y no lo estaba tomando bien, ya que corte lo uso para separar una linea con `split(':')` no habia caido en cuenta que estaba separando la hora y tomaba una fecha mala, ya que lo usaba para separar campos como nombre, codigo.

mi segunda duda es que en el `DateTime.Now` no me guarde la hora si no solo la fecha.

Comment: si inspeccionas la variable corte[2] estas seguro que es una fecha? quizas esta tomando un texto diferente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muy buenas, como te han comentado puedes usar `DateTime.Now.Date` pero si te fijas esto te devuelve la fecha correctamente y la hora **0:00:00**. Si lo que quieres es imprimir la fecha sin la hora puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
MessageBox.Show(dateTime.ToShortDateString());
```

Si lo que quieres es guardar solo la fecha en un objeto `DataTime` deberás usar `DateTime.Now.Date` pero recuerda que al imprimir la fecha debes usar la función `ToShortDateString()` para que no aparezca la hora como **0:00:00**

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres tomar sólo la fecha de una variable DateTime puedes llamar a su propiedad "Date".

Algo así

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Realice la prueba siguiente

```
public static void Main()
{
    string fechaString = "03/09/2018 08:42:18 pm";
    DateTime fecha = DateTime.Parse(fechaString);

    Console.WriteLine("fecha: {0}", fecha);
}
```

como veras esto si puede convertir, solo quite el punto al "p.m"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esto para mostrar solo la fecha sin la hora, lo hace es mostrar desde el caracter 0 al 9 (de adelante hacia atrás) mostrando asi solo la fecha, lo puedes utilizar para todo tipo de formato.

```
if (_ContenidoHTMLPlantilla.Contains("[FECHA]"))
                        {
                            string cadena = Convert.ToString(oDoc.SLI_DAT_FECHASALIDA);
                            string resultado = cadena.Substring(0, 9);
                            _ContenidoHTMLPlantilla = _ContenidoHTMLPlantilla.Replace("[FECHA]", resultado);
                        }
```